# Showing search documents count under each category

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I need to show total documents count for each category in my search results...for example:
Rock(1010)
Blues(5030)
Pop(2209)
:
:

I was reading somewhere that using TopFieldDocCollector is more efficient than HitCollector class.

Given my requirement, how do I use TopFieldDocCollector class?or is there any other approach in Lucene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HitCollector` is an abstract class. `TopDocCollector` and `TopFieldDocCollector` are implementations of that class. They can't be "more efficient" because there's no actual code in `HitCollector`. As for the difference between `TopDocCollector` and `TopFieldDocCollector` - the former is used when you want to sort the results by relevance and the latter is for when you want a custom sort.

Now, regarding your question, check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152127/using-lucene-to-count-results-in-categories/482639#482639) to a similar question.